# Image asset not loading in Ghost Blog

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

By default, the `casper` theme does not sport an `images` folder in its `assets` folder. I created one, and placed a PNG image inside.

Now, in `screen.css` I am building a header that uses a CSS style, that, in its turn, references the image:

```
background: url("../images/logo.png");
```

However, this always returns a 404 - both Chrome and Edge mention that the resource does not exist.

The blog itself is being continuously deployed from a GitHub repo to an Azure website. I restart the website every time I make changes to the CSS, but no variations seem to show the image.

Is there any way to force the `assets/images` folder to be included in the asset lookup?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the blog in question?

Comment: Probably this is not the ideal solution, but you could embed CSS styling in your .hbs file (```<style>....</style>```) and use ```background: url({{asset "images/img.jpg"}});``` The ```asset``` helper points to the ```assets``` folder on your theme. Consider this as a temporary solution, I've tried your setup, it didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easy hacks you can do is adding inline style. Add `background-image` style in the `.hbs` file as inline style.

While giving image source use

```
<img src={{asset "images/logo.png"}}">
```

I'm petty sure this will work.

or you can just specify the absolute url of the image in the stylesheet

```
url('domain.com/images/logo.png')
```